# Rough estimation of m4 cortex processing speed vs desktop processor

Tags: python, preprocessor

Is there a way that i can estimate the processing time of a m4 cortex on some data vs a desktop processor? For a machine learning project i compared a couple of processing technics like RMS and IAV and now i want to make an estimation on how much time it will take for a m4 cortex processor to compute these processing technics. My I7 8750-H takes about 5ms, but can i say something about the proces duration of a m4 cortex with this?

The value can be a rough estimation, doesnt have to be exact.

Comment: How about you run your code on an M4 and tell us?

Comment: Well that is easier said than done :P